# Access variables from onclicklistener android

Tags: java, android, onclick, scope, onclicklistener

**The the problem is how to use variables inside onclick method**, example:

```
String number = "555 12345";

     callbutton.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent phoneCallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                phoneCallIntent.setData(Uri.parse(number));
                startActivity(phoneCallIntent);

            }
    });
```

I tried this solution and failed. Making custom class for onclicklistener.

```
String number = "555 12345";

bt.setOnClickListener(new CallButtonClickListener(number){});


public class CallButtonClickListener implements OnClickListener
{


  String num;
  public CallButtonClickListener(String number) {
       this.num = number;
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v)
  {
        Intent phoneCallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        phoneCallIntent.setData(Uri.parse(num));
        startActivity(phoneCallIntent);
  }

};

}
```

**How can I pass the string to onclick?** I can't define the string inside onclick because I have to use it multiple times.

Comment: Declare the variable as a class member

Comment: Did you try using ParentActivity.number ?

Answer (score 3):

Make it `final`:

```
final String number = "555 12345";
```

Also the second solution seems alright also as you're passing a copy of the reference. What't wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Use final variable or declare them outside `onCreate()` method